# Multiple set of data in mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am working on a mean stack app. what i have is a set of users and a set of table entries(files) for each particular user. The number of users and files will gradually increase. i am not sure how to handle this is in mongoose and express?

PS. I am using passport for authentication and client side routing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using all-in-one app stacks (meanjs or something).

I'll an example how I define mongoose models and use it routers.

It should be something like that:

in `/models/User.js` :

```
var 
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  pwd: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true
  },
  files: {
    type: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
    required: false,
    default: []
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

in routing files somewhere:

```
var User = require('./models/User');

app.post('/user/:_id/file', function(req, res) {

  var file = {filename: 'blabla.jpg', some: 'other data'}; // this will be file that will be handled by post request

  User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params._id,
    {$push: {"files": file}},
    {safe: true, upsert: true},
    function(err, model) {
       // callbacks and etc here
    });
});
```

Comment: i am sorry for missing details. 
my data should look somthing like this

{_id:{
name:
email:
pwd:
files: {file1, file2}}}, (files contain multiple fields too.)

what i want is mongoose schema to handle both, users and files of a user. The web app displays each users list of files and details once logged in